# use Java to call python,I used to work in windows,it's ok.But get problem when I deploy the project on linux

Tags: java, linux, nmap

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:
I use java to develop my project.In the process of working, I need to use Java to call python.as follows:(windos enviroment)

```
String[] args1 = new String[] { "C:\\anaconda\\envs\\test\\python.exe",
                "src/main/java/cn/ihep/python/testNmap.py", ipAddrs, port, scanModel };
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args1);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
String line;
StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    res.append(line);
}
```

in windows enviroment, my work is ok!

But, later, I want to deploy the project to linux, so, I need to modify the phthon interpreter. As follows:(on linux)

```
String[] args1 = new String[] { "python",
                "src/main/java/cn/ihep/python/testNmap.py", ipAddrs, port, scanModel };
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args1);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
String line;
StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    res.append(line);
}
```

in linux enviroment, my python version is 2.7.5.

---

the function of the code above is to detect asset by Nmap(open source tool).of cource, I have installed in windows and Linux. The path as follows:

```
portScanner = nmap.PortScanner(nmap_search_path=('nmap', '/usr/bin/nmap', '/usr/local/bin/nmap', '/sw/bin/nmap', r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe'));
```

the path in windows: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe';
the path in Linux: '/usr/bin/nmap'.

I think the Nmap path in above code should be Ok.May be I was Wrong, Are there any friends with similar problems???

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem? What is the error message?

Comment: `res.append(line').append("\n");`

Comment: sorry,little nervous.THE qestion is :  I can not detect asset on web page if I deploy it on linux .  But if it work in windows, it is ok.

Comment: And what does "I can not detect asset on web page" mean? Empty output? Error message?

Comment: yeah,"Empty output"
console.log(response) as follows:
pageList:
endRow: 0
firstPage: 0
hasNextPage: false
hasPreviousPage: false
isFirstPage: false
isLastPage: true
lastPage: 0
list: [__ob__: Ce]
navigateFirstPage: 0
navigateLastPage: 0
navigatePages: 4
navigatepageNums: []
nextPage: 0
pageNum: 0
pageSize: 5
pages: 0
prePage: 0
size: 0
startRow: 0
total: 0